# NPM not working after initial Node package install

Tags: node.js, macos, bash, npm

So I've got a brand new Macbook Pro running 10.10.3 (14D2134). I installed `Node.js` via their package installer you can download on https://nodejs.org/

From there I attempted to install `grunt` via NPM but after getting the error `-bash: npm: command not found` I realized NPM might need to installed in addition to the initial install of Node.

I tried removing Node all together following these instructions: [How do I completely uninstall Node.js, and reinstall from beginning (Mac OS X)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177954/how-do-i-completely-uninstall-node-js-and-reinstall-from-beginning-mac-os-x) with the intention of reinstalling both Node and NPM via Homebrew. However, after following the above instructions and attempting to install Node with Homebrew, I recieved an error saying that Node is already installed (apparently I didn't completely remove every trace of it) but it just wasn't linked. So I followed the command line prompts to link Node and did so successfully.

So here I am with Node installed but still getting this nonsense. Please send help. xoxo.

`Last login: Mon Jun 29 08:36:45 on ttys000
Jeremys-MacBook-Pro:~ jeremypbeasley$ node -v
v0.12.5
Jeremys-MacBook-Pro:~ jeremypbeasley$ npm install
-bash: npm: command not found
Jeremys-MacBook-Pro:~ jeremypbeasley$`

I also tried `sudo npm install npm -g` then Password but got `sudo: npm: command not found`

I also tried looking into the path if this helps:

`Jeremys-MacBook-Pro:~ jeremypbeasley$ which node
/usr/local/bin/node
Jeremys-MacBook-Pro:~ jeremypbeasley$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
Jeremys-MacBook-Pro:~ jeremypbeasley$ ls -al /usr/local/bin/npm /usr/local/lib/node_modules
ls: /usr/local/bin/npm: No such file or directory
/usr/local/lib/node_modules:
total 0
drwxrwxr-x  2 502  staff   68 Jun 28 11:11 .
drwxrwxr-x  5 502  staff  170 Jun 28 11:24 ..
Jeremys-MacBook-Pro:~ jeremypbeasley$`

Comment: `npm` gets installed when you install Node so it's a bit of a puzzle. Can you add the output of `which node` and `echo $PATH` to your question?

Comment: Added! Thanks so much. Looks like there's some weird repetition in my path but I don't really know what to do with it.

Comment: Can you also add the output for this: `ls -al /usr/local/bin/npm /usr/local/lib/node_modules`

Comment: Your installation seems to be incomplete (well duh ;-). I can only suggest reinstalling using the official installer (the pkg version) once more (I use Homebrew myself, it's awesome, but for Node I use the official installer), after removing the Homebrew version first.

Comment: What's the most sure way to remove all versions of Node completely and start from scratch?

Comment: You can try uninstalling the Homebrew package first (`brew uninstall node`), and run the official Node installer after that.

Answer (score 0):

Those uninstall instructions are pretty old (written in 2012). I'd start by figuring out which installation of node your computer is using:

```
which node
```

You'll get something like:

```
/usr/local/bin/node
```

Follow that path (in Finder select Go > Go to folder... or hit shirt + command + g and paste the path). Node will either be an executation file or a link. If it's a link, follow it. It probably leads to homebrew's installation. That would be:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/node
```

If you haven't installed Xcode Command Line Tools, try that:

```
xcode-select --install
```

Let me know what you find.

Comment: Thanks! Xcode command line tools are installed already. `which node` responded with exactly what you wrote above. I went there in Finder and found the file `node` which is a link. I click the link and it opens Terminal with `~ jeremypbeasley$ /usr/local/Cellar/node/0.12.5/bin/node ; exit;
>` If I select "Get Info" on the link file, it shows "Original: /usr/local/Cellar/node/0.12.5/bin/node" where I find the executable file in Finder.